# how can i multiple populate in same query using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I need multiple populate in the same query.

`User.find({$or:[{region: "NA"},{sector:"Some Sector"}]}, function(err, user)`
`{`
`if (err)`
`{`
`res.send(err);`
`}`
`console.log(user);`
`res.json(user);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Post.model.js**

```
const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    postTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

**Query like this**

```
const posts = await Post.find()
      .populate('users', '_id firstName lastName email');
```